# Can I eject Guest Additions CD image after installation?

Tags: 22.04, virtualbox, guest-additions, eject

To enable fullscreen on my guest VM (Ubuntu 22.04.1), I inserted Guest Addition CD image and ran the appropriate executable file (VBoxLinuxAdditions.run) which solved the fullscreen problem but now in my Favorites bar I have the VBox_GAs_7.0.10 disk and I was wondering if I can Eject it now that it served its purpose or do I have to keep it in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, once the additions are installed, you can safely eject it.